# Lua - Computercraft - attempt to call nil, but works sometimes..?

Tags: variables, lua, null, computercraft

Everytime [this program](http://pastebin.com/d8VkATW3) startup , the program runs after a server restart this error shows up:

> startup:13: attempt to call nil

When i comment out that line of code the same happens to the line after that, and after that.

Until all those four lines are. (the `round(math.floor)` lines)
Then the program starts.

The four variables is needed in the program so it wont run well with them commented out.

If i now uncomment those lines the program starts perfectly and everything works.

Any reason what im doing wrong?

Comment: Post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here, instead of a link.

Comment: Functions must be defined before they are called (`round` is defined on line 72). Try adding `local round` on a line before `while true do` on line 5.

Comment: Since the suggestion solved your issue I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions must be defined before they are called (`round` is defined on line 72, but called on line 5). You can declare a function prior to defining it:

```
function program()
    local round -- forward declaration
    while true do

        -- call function defined below
        turbEnergy = round(math.floor(turbine.getEnergyStored())/100000,1) 

        -- function definition
        function round(val, decimal)                
        end
```